# Нужно скрыть поле ввода при смене опции select

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#shipping-method').change(function() {
    $('.ss').slideDown();
    $('.ss').hide();
    $("." + $(this).val()).slideToggle();
    $("." + $(this).val()).show();
    $(this).next().show();
  });
});
```

```css
.ss {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields-group">
  <label for="delivery">  Метод доставки:</label><br>
  <br>
  <select name="shipping_method" id="shipping-method" class="form-control large-field">
    <option value="{&quot;title&quot;: &quot;До Двери&quot;, &quot;code&quot;: &quot;flat.flat&quot;, &quot;comment&quot;:&quot;&quot;, &quot;shipping_method&quot;:&quot;flat.flat&quot;, &quot;cost&quot;:&quot;5.00&quot;,&quot;tax_class_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"
      class="form-control large-field flat">До Двери</option>
    <option value="{&quot;title&quot;: &quot;До терминала&quot;, &quot;code&quot;: &quot;citylink.citylink&quot;, &quot;comment&quot;:&quot;&quot;, &quot;shipping_method&quot;:&quot;citylink.citylink&quot;, &quot;cost&quot;:&quot;0.1&quot;,&quot;tax_class_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"
      class="form-control large-field citylink">До терминала</option>
  </select>
  <div class="ss">
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery-type" value="delivery">
    <label for="address_1"> По адресу:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="address_1" id="address_1" value="post hame" class="form-control large-field" placeholder="  № отделения / адрес">
    <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Это кусок из OpenCart 2. `Checkout` переделанный.
Подскажите, что не так и как сделать чтобы скрывало/показывало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var sel = document.querySelector('select');

sel.addEventListener('change', function () { 
  var inpt = document.querySelector('#address_1');
   inpt.style.display = inpt.style.display == 'none'? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```css
.ss {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields-group">
  <label for="delivery">  Метод доставки:</label><br>
  <br>
  <select name="shipping_method" id="shipping-method" class="form-control large-field">
    <option value="{&quot;title&quot;: &quot;До Двери&quot;, &quot;code&quot;: &quot;flat.flat&quot;, &quot;comment&quot;:&quot;&quot;, &quot;shipping_method&quot;:&quot;flat.flat&quot;, &quot;cost&quot;:&quot;5.00&quot;,&quot;tax_class_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"
      class="form-control large-field flat">До Двери</option>
    <option value="{&quot;title&quot;: &quot;До терминала&quot;, &quot;code&quot;: &quot;citylink.citylink&quot;, &quot;comment&quot;:&quot;&quot;, &quot;shipping_method&quot;:&quot;citylink.citylink&quot;, &quot;cost&quot;:&quot;0.1&quot;,&quot;tax_class_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"
      class="form-control large-field citylink">До терминала</option>
  </select>
  <div class="ss">
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery-type" value="delivery">
    <label for="address_1"> По адресу:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="address_1" id="address_1" value="post hame" class="form-control large-field" placeholder="  № отделения / адрес">
    <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Заменил на такой код и всё заработало:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#shipping-method').on('change', f_acc);
});

function f_acc() {
  $('.ss').not($(this).next()).slideToggle();
  $(this).next().slideUp();
  $('.ss').show();
}
```

```css
.ss {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields-group">
  <label for="delivery">  Метод доставки:</label><br>
  <br>
  <select name="shipping_method" id="shipping-method" class="form-control large-field">
    <option value="{&quot;title&quot;: &quot;До Двери&quot;, &quot;code&quot;: &quot;flat.flat&quot;, &quot;comment&quot;:&quot;&quot;, &quot;shipping_method&quot;:&quot;flat.flat&quot;, &quot;cost&quot;:&quot;5.00&quot;,&quot;tax_class_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"
      class="form-control large-field flat">До Двери</option>
    <option value="{&quot;title&quot;: &quot;До терминала&quot;, &quot;code&quot;: &quot;citylink.citylink&quot;, &quot;comment&quot;:&quot;&quot;, &quot;shipping_method&quot;:&quot;citylink.citylink&quot;, &quot;cost&quot;:&quot;0.1&quot;,&quot;tax_class_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"
      class="form-control large-field citylink">До терминала</option>
  </select>
  <div class="ss">
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery-type" value="delivery">
    <label for="address_1"> По адресу:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="address_1" id="address_1" value="post hame" class="form-control large-field" placeholder="  № отделения / адрес">
    <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```